# How can create a dropdown without using absolute or negative value

Tags: html, css

I have a task to create a drop-down menu and i create it with using absolute and negative value but i can change my mind i want to create a drop-down without using absolute there is any possibility to create and how can do it kindly help in this query

```css
.mainmenu {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.mainmenu:hover {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.mainmenu:hover .submenu {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 50px;
  height: auto;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}

.mainmenu:hover .hide_line {
  height: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu">
  Menu
  <div class="hide_line">
  </div>
  <div class="submenu">

    submenu
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do it without using absolute . just change 'position: absolute' to 'relative'

Answer (score 0):

You can use list for this purpose

```css
.mainmenu a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000000;
}
.mainmenu {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    list-style:none;
}
.mainmenu > li{
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
}
.submenu {
  opacity:0;
  list-style:none;
}
.mainmenu:hover .submenu {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
}
.submenu li{
    padding-left:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href='#'>Main Menu</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href='#'>Sub menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope you can do rest of the formatting